# How to reference k8s secret in a nested object in values.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have such values.yaml

```
test-app:
  properties:
    data:
      password: // how to reference the secret PASSWORD
```

and secret.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
data:
  PASSWORD: xxx
```

Secret is already created. How do I reference the secret `PASSWORD` in the values under `test-app` -> `properties` -> `data` -> `password`?

Comment: Are you trying to create the Secret value from the configuration; `{{ .Values.test-app.properties.data.password | b64enc }}`; or something else?

Comment: no, im trying to reference a secret `PASSWORD` in the values

Answer (score 0):

You need to create secret with test-app.properties.data.password passed as a file.

secret.yaml

```
test-app:
  properties:
    data:
      password: <password>
```

Run the below command to create secret.

kubectl create secret generic sample-secret --from-file=secret.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  secret.yaml: dGVzdC1hcHA6CiAgcHJvcGVydGllczoKICAgIGRhdGE6CiAgICAgIHBhc3N3b3JkOiB0c3QxMjMK
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: sample
```

Then in deployment manifest you need to refer this as volume and volumemount as below and in application code they can directly refer that corresponding property.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: secret-dotfiles-pod
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: secret-volume
      secret:
        secretName: sample-secret
  containers:
    - name: dotfile-test-container
      image: registry.k8s.io/busybox
      volumeMounts:
        - name: secret-volume
          readOnly: true
          mountPath: "/etc/secret-volume"
```

Comment: Thanks! but the values will be passed to another chart, there is no deployment, any idea how to make this work?